# Bootstrap-4 - Trying to do smooth gradient hover on the row

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

im trying to do gradient effect following the curent position of mouse (only for rows in table).
I think that the bootstrap make that this problem occurs. When im taking bootstrap reference into the comment, my following gradient works fine. Without it its not working on childs elements of row.

I was trying to fix it with js

```
        for (var i = 0; i < childs.length; i++) {

            var child = childs[i];

            for (var j = 0; j < child.length; j++) {

                child[j].addEventListener("mousemove", function (event) {
                    return false;
                }, false);
            }
        }
```

Here is my full code
http://jsfiddle.net/0t7k4xzb/2/

Comment: Could you add more about the problem that you're trying to get help with? All I can tell for certain is that this gradient effect you're working on is not functioning as you desire. I played around with your fiddle page, thanks for including that, and it seemed to work great if you mouse over from right to left, but not vice versa.

Comment: Its working only when you are moving mouse on the row, in the space not colliding with child elements of the row. When we are moving mouse on the top of row, its working fine, but, when we are trying to do this in the center on row, this gradient jumping form one place to another, becouse its colliding on the childs elements of row